# How to see ELKI DBSCAN clustering result

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, dbscan, elki

I am using ELKI for DBSCAN clustering of some ~14,000 GPS points.Its running fine but I want to see information about clusters like how many points are in a cluster.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `-resulthandler ResultWriter` and output to text, the cluster sizes will be at the top of each cluster file.

The visualizer currently doesn't seem to show cluster sizes.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the -resulthandler ResultWriter and output to text, the cluster sizes will be at the top of each cluster file.

Also, if you want to merge all those results into a single file, here is a python script that works:

```
clusterout_path = "path/to/where/files/all/go/"
finalout_path = "/path/for/single/merged/file/"
consol_filename= "single_merged_file.txt"

cll_file = open(finalout_path + consol_filename,"a")
cll_file.write("ClusterID"+ "\t" + "Lon" + "\t" + "Lat" + "\n")
def readFile(file):
    f = open(clusterout_path + file)
    counter = 0
    cluster = ""
    lon = ""
    lat = ""
    for line in f.readlines():
        counter+=1
        if counter == 1:
            cluster = line.split(":")[1].strip().lower()

        if counter > 4 and line.startswith("ID"):
            arr = line.split(" ")
            lon = arr[1]
            lat = arr[2]
            cll_file.write(cluster + "\t" + lon + "\t" + lat + "\n") 
    f.close()

listing = os.listdir(clusterout_path)
for infile in listing:
    print "Processing file: " + infile
    readFile(infile) 

cll_file.close()
```